# Why does my display look different on iPhone simulator vs. iPad simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I am working on a puzzle app on Xcode Version 11.0. My app displays as expected on my physical iPad mini and also on the iPhone simulators, but if I use an iPad simulator it appears to switch the orientation to Portrait mode and display my secondary screen as a popup on top of the secondary screen (see the images below).

I am using an "Action Segue" to get from my 1st screen to my 2nd screen. I have tried several different options (Show, Show Detail, Show Modally, Present As Popover). The result is slightly different, but all of them give the "Portrait popup" look. I am guessing that this is a newer feature, and I just need to set some flag to avoid it, but I don't have any guesses on what to look for. Could anyone offer some help?

iPhone 8 Simulator (this is what I want it to look like)
[image: iPhone 8 Simulator (this is what I want it to look like)]

iPad Simulator (with undesired Portrait popup appearance)
[image: iPad Simulator (with undesired Portrait popup appearance)]

Comment: Could someone let me know why I am getting down votes for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the segue to be Show Modally and also Fullscreen (instead of Automatic).

Comment: This has the trick! Thanks! Just to clarify, this is what I did: I changed the segue to "Present Modally". I then clicked on the segue line that was drawn between the view controllers, changed to "Show the Attributes Inspector", and set the "Presentation" to "Full Screen". Thanks matt!